Changing formatting for control characters when using QScintilla and PyQt5
I am working on a simple editor using QScintilla (the Qt port of Scintilla) and PyQt5. I can replace certain characters using SCI_SETREPRESENTATION (for e.g. I can show '-' instead of a space). However, all control characters are rendered inverted on a black background. I have read in the docs that the function SCI_SETREPRESENTATIONAPPEARANCE can be used to control the appearance but this function is not implemented in the port.
Is there an alternate method to format the display of control characters using QScintilla?

The only alternative is to define a style for STYLE_CONTROLCHAR, but that doesn't support setting colour attributes. The QScintilla port uses a legacy branch of Scintilla which is now several major versions behind the main branch. The legacy release history provides download links for the source code of the currently ported version (3.10.1), which also includes version-specific Scintilla docs.
